# How to show Ocean Contours on Mapbox Style?

Tags: mapbox, contour, ocean

My users would like to be able to see the ocean contour lines as they zoom in. But mapbox outdoors style only seems to provide contours for land.

I'm not a GIS pro but a web dev, so please keep that in mind in any answers. I do have experience in publishing my own tilesets to mapbox with points, shapes, and labels. But a tileset with all of the contours for the entire water area of the earth sounds impractical and very large for me to host on my little portion of mapbox. But I don't see that they have such a layers available.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model works. It is expected that Questions show work toward solving the problem. Posting unclear questions without any display of effort is likely to result in downvoting and may it close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the Mapbox custom map style "[North Star](https://www.mapbox.com/designer-maps/#north-star)" which is using [1:10m bathymetry data from Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-bathymetry/).

Here is a blog post from the style designer with some more information on this:

https://blog.mapbox.com/designing-north-star-c8574e299c94

It is possible to use the Natural Earth bathymetry data also with other styles.